# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am facing this error which says that type number is not assignable to type undefined on last digit (i.e. 1) in scale={[1.618, 1, 1]}. Does anyone knows how can I remove this typescript error?

```
"use client";

import * as THREE from "three";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Image } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Mesh } from "three";
import { easing } from "maath";

interface CardProps {
  onPointerOver: (index: any) => void;
  onPointerOut: () => void;
  position: [number, number, number];
  rotation: [number, number, number];
  active: boolean;
  hovered: boolean;
  url: string;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ url, active, hovered, ...props }) => {
  const ref = useRef<Mesh>(null!);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    const f = hovered ? 1.4 : active ? 1.25 : 1;

    easing.damp3(ref.current.position, [0, hovered ? 0.25 : 0, 0], 0.1, delta);
    easing.damp3(ref.current.scale, [1.618 * f, 1 * f, 1], 0.15, delta);
  });

  return (
    <group {...props}>
      <Image
        ref={ref}
        url={url}
        scale={[1.618, 1, 1]}
        side={THREE.DoubleSide}
        alt=""
      />
    </group>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: How do you know that's where the issue is coming from?  Can you provide the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: This is the exact error that I mentioned! I don't know how about stack trace!

Comment: Where do you see this error? If in the browser, maybe take a screenshot of the error in the console, or right-click on the line in the console and copy the full error message to paste into your post?

Comment: It seems like the property scale of the Image component from "@react-three/drei" does not support your array with 3 numbers as input. When you look into the component definition you see thats the property scale is typed either as a number or an array with two number:
https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/master/src/core/Image.tsx